# Printing on the FILE port with a given output path still shows the "save as" dialog

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, ghostscript

My application uses GDI printing to create postscript files then converted to PDF.
My printer use Ghostscript PDF driver and the FILE port
(By the way why it is named "PDF driver" if it cannot output pdf directly)

I specify a file output path with the DOCINFO struct `docInfo.lpszOutput = L"c:\temp_path\{guid}.ps";`

Everything works fine. But sporadically the driver prompt the "save as" dialog, despite I provided an output filename.

The program runs server side so this prompt dialog is problematic.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Build Printer Port driver and make file save there. I think the Save As dialog is displayed by `FILE` port driver always.

Comment: The dialog isn't display if lpszOutput is provided. But sometimes it does. For no reason...

Comment: I had similar problem with XPS printer and created Printer Port driver. In WDK (DDK) exists sample printer port.